# Inserting message, iMessage application swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, imessage, imessage-extension

So basically I have been trying to create a very simple iMessage application where when a button is pressed, it inserts a message into the conversation a bit like what can be seen in this tutorial: The only issue I am having is that when the button is pressed, it runs the function however, nothing occurs as a result and I am really unsure as to why this is the case. I have been struggling with finding a working solution to this problem for a little while now and would really appreciate if someone would be kind enough to take a quick look at my code and perhaps point out where I went wrong or if I'm missing something. Any help on the topic will be greatly appreciated, thank you.

```
 @IBAction func funcSend(_ sender: Any) {

    let conversation = activeConversation
    let session = conversation?.selectedMessage?.session

    let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
    layout.caption = "Hi there"

    var components = URLComponents()
    let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "key", value: "value")
    components.queryItems = [queryItem]

    let message = MSMessage(session: session!)
    message.layout = layout
    message.url = components.url
    message.summaryText = "Sent hi there message"

    conversation?.insert(message)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks right, try to call *dismiss()* at the end?

Here's the code that works for me

```
@IBAction func onSend(_ sender: Any) {
    print("sending...")
    guard let conversation = activeConversation else { fatalError("Expected a conversation") }
    guard let message = composeMessage(session: conversation.selectedMessage?.session)
        else { return }

    // Add the message to the conversation.
    conversation.insert(message) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
    // This one
    dismiss()
}
```

And how I'm create the message

```
// MARK: Messaging
func composeMessage(session: MSSession? = nil) -> MSMessage? {
    let layout = MSMessageTemplateLayout()
    var components = URLComponents()
    let caption = URLQueryItem(name: "caption", value: self.melody)
    let decodedMelody = URLQueryItem(name: "melody", value: self.melody)

    components.queryItems = [caption, decodedMelody]

    let message = MSMessage(session: session ?? MSSession())
    layout.image = self.screenImage.image

    layout.caption = "Melody built with haptic and vibro."
    layout.subcaption = "sent via iVibrio"
    message.summaryText = "something summary"

    if let conversation = activeConversation,
        let msg = conversation.selectedMessage{

        if msg.senderParticipantIdentifier == conversation.localParticipantIdentifier {
            layout.caption =  "$\(msg.senderParticipantIdentifier.uuidString) My msg"
        }
        else{
            layout.caption =  "$\(msg.senderParticipantIdentifier.uuidString) Edited msg"
        }
    }

    message.url = components.url!
    message.layout = layout

    return message
}
```

[Link to the complete example/code](http://www.mikitamanko.com/blog/2017/10/20/swift-how-to-create-an-interactive-imessage-application/)